# How to add labels from a property using periodic commit

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I read in a CSV file which has a property named `node.lab`, which contains list of labels. I want to split and add it as labels on each node.

As Number of nodes are huge, i want to wrap it with `apoc.periodic.commit`.

I tried the following query but there are issues which I am not able to understand fully.

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (n:Node)
WITH n limit {limit}, split(n.lab) as labels
call apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), labels) yield node
with node
remove node.lab
remove node:Node ", {limit:100000});
```

I feel the second line of the query has some issue but not able to figure it out.  Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause should be used in the end of the `WITH` clause:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (n:Node)
    WITH n, split(n.lab) as labels limit {limit} call 
    apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), labels) yield node
    with node
    remove node.lab
    remove node:Node",
{limit:100000});
```

Comment: Bruno,
Thanks for quick reply. Actually n.lab is not list. It is a comma separated string. 
For Ex: "instance,cell,pin".
So I have to use split.
with both split and limit I am not able to get the syntax correct.

Comment: @sranga Right. So moving the LIMIT to the end of the with should be enough `call apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (n:Node)
 WITH n, split(n.lab) as labels limit {limit}
 call apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), labels) yield node
 with node
 remove node.lab
 remove node:Node ",
{limit:100000});
`

Comment: @sranga you are welcome! I will update my answer, then you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.